# how to get the URL of an external properties file in classpath in TOMCAT 10

Tags: java, tomcat9

I have an external properties file named myAccount.properties.  This file resides in a folder called `${catalina.home}/usmo/MyAccount/resources/properties`.  This folder is being added to the class path thru context.xml using configuration below:

```
<Resources className="org.apache.catalina.webresources.StandardRoot">
    <PostResources className="org.apache.catalina.webresources.DirResourceSet"
        base="${catalina.home}/usmo/MyAccount/resources/properties"
        internalPath="/"
        webAppMount="/WEB-INF/classes" />
</Resources>
```

I am expecting code below to return the URL or absolute path of this file.  Sadly,  it is returning a null. Any help would be appreciated.

```
URL url = MyClass.class.getClassLoader().getResource( "myAccount.properties" );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out to be case sensitive issue.  The actual file named is 'MyAccount.properties'.  But the code uses 'myAccount.properties'.  I change the code to below and it works:

```
URL url = MyClass.class.getClassLoader().getResource( "MyAccount.properties" );
```

Weird behavior though:

1. The code is running in Windows OS, which is a case insensitive.
2. The code works fine in TOMCAT 7 under java 8.  But failed in TOMCAT 8 under java 11.